# How do I select a range of columns that are datetimes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, slice

I have a dataframe in which the column headers are datetimes starting from the current day to midnight of the next day.

```
    index|  2021-06-15 00:00:00    2021-06-15 01:00:00    2021-06-15 02:00:00 ..... 2021-06-15 12:00:00 .... 2021-07-15 00:00:00
    0    |   nan
```

I'm trying to create a new dataframe with a range of dates that are the column headers.  I've tried this but my new data frame is empty.  I'm trying to create shift schedules so the first shift is from midnight to noon and the second shift is noon to midnight of the next day

```
    d2ashift = day1.loc[:, (day1.columns >= '00:00:00') & (day1.columns <= '12:00:00')]
```

My new dataframe should look like this d2shift =

```
    index|   2021-06-15 00:00:00   2021-06-15 01:00:00   2021-06-15 02:00:00 .... 2021-06-15 12:00:00
    0         nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d2shift = day1[day1.columns[day1.columns <= day1.columns[0] + pd.DateOffset(hours=12)]]
```